# How to reuse default iphone app feature in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, image

My app need to create user avatar. During the process, it allows user to edit the selected image. I found that in Apple camera app has edit image feature. How can i reuse that feature in my app?

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329030/edit-image-after-taking-a-picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse Apple's APP but SDK. As I'm aware Photos and PhotosUI were designed for photo display and edit. Just search them in Apple Developer Website.